# How to use <ui:repeat> tag inside datalist: primefaces mobile?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces-mobile

Sorry im just a beginner both in english and primefaces mobile.

I want to use ui:repeat within a datalist to do something like:

```
<p:dataList id="data" var="tache" value="#{affect.listeDesTaches}">
                       <p:panel id="basic" header="Taches n° #{tache.idTache}"  style="padding-bottom:40px">
                            <ui:repeat id="etapesId" var="etapes" value="#{taches.liste}" >

                               <p:panelGrid columns="6">

                                    <p:commandButton value="#{etapes.idEtape}"  type="button"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{etapes.name}" type="button"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{etapes.description}" type="button"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{etapes.dimension}" type="button"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{etapes.tempsFab}" type="button"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{etapes.reste}" type="button"/>
                                </p:panelGrid>    

                        </ui:repeat>
                        </p:panel>
                </p:dataList>
```

but it not working in primefaces mobile.I have no error message and all the information in the interior of "ui-repeat" are not displayed. please help.
PS: i'm using primefaces mobile 0.9.4 and primefaces 5.0

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "not working"? do you see any error messages, or can you post a sample html output?

Comment: I have no error message and all the information in the interior of "ui-repeat" tag are not displayed. i can only see all the panel (empty) of "listeDesTaches".

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo. please use `value="#{tache.liste}"` instead of `value="#{taches.liste}"`.